# application.undo works when using 'enter' but not if clicking on another cell

Tags: excel

I have a routine that collects the old value after a change.
It is based on examples in this board using the undo method to collect the old value.
We are finding that if the cell is changed by hitting an 'Enter', then the Application.undo will work.  If the cell is changed by clicking on another cell, the Application.Undo will not work.
Here is my code thus far:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim nextRow As Integer
    Dim oldValues As Variant
    Dim newValues As Variant
    Dim oldRev, newRev, diffRev As Double
    Dim NumRows, NumCols As Integer
    Dim lRow, lCol As Integer

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Small")) Is Nothing Then
       ' On Error GoTo err

        NumRows = Target.Cells.Rows.Count
        NumCols = Target.Cells.Columns.Count

        newValues = Target.Value2

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        oldValues = Target.Value2
        ...
```

In both cases, the value in the cell does change. 
In both cases, the worksheet change triggers.
It is just that the undo doesn't work unless an Enter is used.
Thanks for any help.
Rich